# Error:scalac: Class com.amazonaws.services.s3.event.S3EventNotification not found - continuing with a stub

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to handle a S3 event with aws lambda. The following is the **build.sbt** file, which is modified from [Writing AWS Lambda Functions in Scala](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/writing-aws-lambda-functions-in-scala/):

```
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8", "-Xlint")

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "lambda-demo",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.4",
    retrieveManaged := true
  )

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-core" % "1.1.0",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-events" % "1.0.0"
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

And the very simply **Main.scala**:

```
package example;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.S3Event

class Main {
  def myHandler(event: S3Event, context: Context): String = s"Hello $event"
}
```

It failed to compile with the following:

> Error:scalac: Class com.amazonaws.services.s3.event.S3EventNotification not found - continuing with a stub.

It seems like it is missing dependencies and I added the `aws-java-sdk`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.11.179",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-core" % "1.1.0",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-events" % "1.0.0"
)
```

And it compiles fine!! But then I realize that the package size is 79MB which is more than the hard limit of a lambda function: 50MB. Any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I realize that I don't have to include the `aws-java-sdk`. The only thing that I need is the s3 related part. After changing the dependency to the following, it works fine.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-s3" % "1.11.179",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-core" % "1.1.0",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-events" % "1.0.0"
)
```

The final package size is only 11.8MB, way smaller than the 50MB limit.